# Animated SVGs don't animate until page is loaded

Tags: jquery, css, animation, svg

My site contains quite a lot of ads, and these take a while to load. This isn't a problem exactly, but I've noticed any SVG animations will draw the first frame instantly, but the animation comes only after all the loading has completed on the page. The SVG animations usually indicate a spinner/loading icon.
Is there a method to start the SVG animation instantly?
Or if I convert it to pure CSS would it animate instantly?

This is my svg loader code:
http://jsfiddle.net/5zq5j4d9/

```
<div class="loading-icon-outer">
    <div class="loading-icon">
        <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px" width="20px" height="20px" viewBox="0 0 20 20" style="enable-background:new 0 0 50 50;" xml:space="preserve">
            <rect x="0" y="8" width="4" height="4" fill="#333" opacity="0.2">
                <animate attributeName="opacity" attributeType="XML" values="0.2; 1; 0.2" begin="0s" dur="0.6s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
                <animate attributeName="height" attributeType="XML" values="4; 20; 4" begin="0s" dur="0.6s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
                <animate attributeName="y" attributeType="XML" values="8; 0; 8" begin="0s" dur="0.6s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
            </rect>
            <rect x="8" y="8" width="4" height="4" fill="#333"  opacity="0.2">
                <animate attributeName="opacity" attributeType="XML" values="0.2; 1; 0.2" begin="0.15s" dur="0.6s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
                <animate attributeName="height" attributeType="XML" values="4; 20; 4" begin="0.15s" dur="0.6s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
                <animate attributeName="y" attributeType="XML" values="8; 0; 8" begin="0.15s" dur="0.6s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
            </rect>
            <rect x="16" y="8" width="4" height="4" fill="#333"  opacity="0.2">
                <animate attributeName="opacity" attributeType="XML" values="0.2; 1; 0.2" begin="0.3s" dur="0.6s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
                <animate attributeName="height" attributeType="XML" values="4; 20; 4" begin="0.3s" dur="0.6s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
                <animate attributeName="y" attributeType="XML" values="8; 0; 8" begin="0.3s" dur="0.6s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
            </rect>
        </svg>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There's an example similar to yours on codePen ... using AnimateTransform for loading ... http://codepen.io/aurer/pen/jEGbA

Comment: That's where I got the loader icon from. Is AnimateTransform something different to what I'm using? Will it play the animation instantly on loading a page?

Comment: Not sure ... I didn't have any issues with your code, but was hesitant to say that since some people will want to close the question.  It may be in the timing of the load, since you have a lot going on.  Is this HTML being loaded from a separate file or in the main HTML file where it should run?  Are the calls for ads being loaded at the end of the body section?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for the late response. I eventually just translated it to LESS and LESShat and this loads instantly.

http://jsfiddle.net/z84yd0to/2/

I can't use LESS in a jsfiddle so i had to use the output css, but the LESS/LESShat code I used was the following:

```
.loading-icon {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;

    .rect {
        background-color: black;
        height: 100%;
        width: 4px;
        float:left;
        .animation(loading-rect 0.60s infinite ease-in-out);

        & ~ .rect {
            margin-left:4px;
        }
    }

    .rect1 { .animation-delay(-0.30s); }

    .rect2 { .animation-delay(-0.20s); }

    .rect3 { .animation-delay(-0.10s); }
}


.keyframes(~'loading-rect, 0%, 100% { transform: scaleY(0.2); opacity: 0.2; } 50% { transform: scaleY(1.0); opacity: 1; }');
```

Answer (score 4):

To start animations as early as possible (before load has been triggered) the SVG2 spec has added the [timelineBegin](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/struct.html#SVGElementTimelineBeginAttribute) attribute. This was also part of SVG Tiny 1.2.

Browser support for `timelineBegin` is still lacking though.

Possible alternatives include using css animations, web animations (created by script, [see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tngt2s8j/)) or animating the svg with script. Of these sadly it's likely only the last one that will work in all browsers.

Comment: I tried timelinebegin and it didn't appear to improve the loading time. Then I tried javascript and found if I didn't use an animation library it wouldn't be very platform friendly. Then I tried animating it with a popular JS animation library called Velocity, this worked ok but there was still a moment where no animation occurred while the page loaded. Then I just decided to ditch the SVG altogether and rewrite it completely in css. This worked a treat!

Answer (score 1):

SVG-animation runs after loading page. However you can use next trick:

```
<iframe width="20px" height="20px" style="border:0" src="data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg version='1.1' id='Layer_1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' x='0px' y='0px' width='20px' height='20px' viewBox='0 0 20 20' style='enable-background:new 0 0 50 50;' xml:space='preserve'%3E%3Crect x='0' y='8' width='4' height='4' fill='%23333' opacity='0.2'%3E%3Canimate attributeName='opacity' attributeType='XML' values='0.2; 1; 0.2' begin='0s' dur='0.6s' repeatCount='indefinite' /%3E%3Canimate attributeName='height' attributeType='XML' values='4; 20; 4' begin='0s' dur='0.6s' repeatCount='indefinite' /%3E%3Canimate attributeName='y' attributeType='XML' values='8; 0; 8' begin='0s' dur='0.6s' repeatCount='indefinite' /%3E%3C/rect%3E%3Crect x='8' y='8' width='4' height='4' fill='%23333' opacity='0.2'%3E%3Canimate attributeName='opacity' attributeType='XML' values='0.2; 1; 0.2' begin='0.15s' dur='0.6s' repeatCount='indefinite' /%3E%3Canimate attributeName='height' attributeType='XML' values='4; 20; 4' begin='0.15s' dur='0.6s' repeatCount='indefinite' /%3E%3Canimate attributeName='y' attributeType='XML' values='8; 0; 8' begin='0.15s' dur='0.6s' repeatCount='indefinite' /%3E%3C/rect%3E%3Crect x='16' y='8' width='4' height='4' fill='%23333' opacity='0.2'%3E%3Canimate attributeName='opacity' attributeType='XML' values='0.2; 1; 0.2' begin='0.3s' dur='0.6s' repeatCount='indefinite' /%3E%3Canimate attributeName='height' attributeType='XML' values='4; 20; 4' begin='0.3s' dur='0.6s' repeatCount='indefinite' /%3E%3Canimate attributeName='y' attributeType='XML' values='8; 0; 8' begin='0.3s' dur='0.6s' repeatCount='indefinite' /%3E%3C/rect%3E%3C/svg%3E"></iframe>
```